# How can i convert system datetime format to Sql Datetime Format

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, datetime, c#-4.0

[image]

[image]

I am using Entity Framework Database First Approach and 
I want to move Date first object to second object First Object is System.DateTime and the date Format is (01-10-2015) but i want to (2015-10-01) for Second Object After Converting Date in to second Object the Second Object inset in to data base 
Can anyone Help me

Comment: why don't you parse the `string` to a `DateTime` object first, and then assign it as usual

Comment: I am using Parse But Still Same result .  can you tell me how can i use parse any one example you have for correct result.

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Are you wanting to get rid of the "Cannot convert string to DateTime" error?

Comment: I want to Date Format (09-22-2015) to  (2015-09-22)this format  in object form  and I insert this object in SQL Database

Comment: I agree, your question is poorly worded. Really you should not be working with date/times as strings but as objects in Sql and in code. So I am guessing you have a `string` / `varchar` that should actually be a date and you want to convert that to another `string` / `varchar` but formatted differently? Or you are doing something completely wrong like mapping a Sql DateTime object to a string in C#. Please include your DDL (sql schema) for both tables and columns and your EF objects.

Comment: If you use a Datetime object, you can use it in sql (or others databases) parameterised queries, and don't need to format it. You just need to format the object as string if you want to show it (textbox, label...) and there is methods for that ex with a Datetime object 'date' :  label.content = date.toShortDateString(); it's just an example. BUT GIVE US SOME DETAILS OF WHAT YOU ARE TRYING TO DO WITH DATES SO WE CAN HELP YOU.

Comment: system Date time   --02-10-2015---convert in to ("yyyy-MM-dd") after converting this format("yyyy-MM-dd") move this format to datetime object  and datetime object insert into  Sql database

Answer (score 1):

Use DateTime.ParseExact:

```
DateTime temp = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: thanks for solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the format:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("10/01/2015 12:00:00 AM", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: thanks for problem solving